# Show multiple Models in same Razor page: OnGet not firing

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, model

On a page in my Razor .Net 6 application I have to show the data of 3 models. So I created a Model EigObjFact, comprising the three needed models:

```
namespace StallingRazor.Model
{
    public class EigObjFact
    {
        public Eigenaar Eigenaren { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Model.Object> Objecten { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Factuur> Facturen { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the Details Page Controller I call the EigObjFact in OnGet:

```
namespace StallingRazor.Pages.Eigenaren
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public DetailsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
    
        public async void OnGetAsync(int id)
        {            
            EigObjFact model = new EigObjFact();
            model.Eigenaren = _db.Eigenarens.Find(id);
            model.Objecten = await _db.Objectens.Where(s => s.EigenarenID == id).ToListAsync();
            model.Facturen = await _db.Facturens.Where(x => x.EigenarenID == id).ToListAsync();
            
        }
    }

}
```

The mapping of the 3 models works fine in the Page because I use:

```
@model StallingRazor.Model.EigObjFact
```

Problem: the OnGetAsync handler in the Details page never fires, so the model is empty when used in the page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model of [razor page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) needs to be a `PageModel` type.So you need to replace `@model StallingRazor.Model.EigObjFact` with `@model StallingRazor.Pages.Eigenaren.DetailsModel`.

And you need to add a property which type is `EigObjFact` to DetailsModel,so that you can get `EigObjFact model` from `DetailsModel`:

```
namespace StallingRazor.Pages.Eigenaren
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public EigObjFact model  { get; set; }= new EigObjFact();
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public DetailsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
    
        public async void OnGetAsync(int id)
        {            
            model.Eigenaren = _db.Eigenarens.Find(id);
            model.Objecten = await _db.Objectens.Where(s => s.EigenarenID == id).ToListAsync();
            model.Facturen = await _db.Facturens.Where(x => x.EigenarenID == id).ToListAsync();
            
        }
    }

}
```

Then if you want to use the data of `EigObjFact model` in view.you can try to use `@Model.model.xxx`.

Comment: Thanks for looking! Unfortunately the changes did not make any difference. Whatever model I use in the Page (EigObjFact or DetailsModel) the error is the same: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when the first line @Model.Eigenaren.EigenarenID is hit. OnGet is bypassed. When I use @@model StallingRazor.Pages.Eigenaren.DetailsModel the data on the Page cannot be mapped.

Comment: Don't use `@@`,use `@model StallingRazor.Pages.Eigenaren.DetailsModel`.And replace `@Model.Eigenaren.EigenarenID` with `@Model.model.Eigenaren.EigenarenID` as I said in my answer.`Then if you want to use the data of EigObjFact model in view.you can try to use @Model.model.xxx.`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. @Model.model.xxx did the trick. Thanks a lot YiYi!